# Handle SIGSEGV Like Signals in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I am facing the SIGSEGV exception in my application and my application is crashing on that. I want to handle these signals so that my application do not crash at runtime instead I handle these exceptions so that the application runs smoothly.

I am using ARC for my application and I am not handling the release or retain statements either and now it is very difficult for me track down why application is accessing the memory for which it has no access or invalid memory.

Also application is crashing all the time it happens very rarely say about in 20 sessions it happens only 1 to 2 times but the problem is there and it is very irritating.

Comment: The right approach is to debug and fix the bug before release. Use the Zombies instrument to find cases where you're messaging an object after deallocation. Use the Static Analyzer to identify memory management bugs for cases that ARC doesn't handle (e.g. Core Foundation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SIGSEGV` is a segmentation fault. There's no way for your application to run smoothly after getting one. Actually there's no way for your application to keep running at all.

You can handle the signal with a signal handler as follows

```
// register a signal handler
signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);

static void SignalHandler (int signo) {
     //...
}
```

but this won't prevent your application from crashing.

Comment: But it is totally OK to write the call stack to a log file using `open()`, `write()` and `close()`, right?